# Parse HTML list using JSoup to create Tree structure

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have HTML lists with the exact same structure that I need to parse using JSoup (my language is Java). Here's an example:

```
<div class="ulist">
  <ul>
    <li><p>Healthy Food</p></li>
    <div class="ulist">
      <ul>
        <li><p>Vegetables</p></li>
        <div class="ulist">
          <ul>
            <li> <p>Carrots</p> </li>
            <li> <p>Lettuce</p> </li>
            <li> <p>Cucumbers</p> </li>
          </ul>
        </div> </li>
        <li> <p>Fruits</p>
          <div class="ulist">
            <ul>
              <li> <p>Apples</p> </li>
              <li> <p>Bananas</p> </li>
              <li> <p>Canned Fruits</p></li>
              <div class="ulist">
                <ul>
                  <li> <p>Peaches</p> </li>
                  <li> <p>Pears</p> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since this data is basically just a Tree data structure, I want to be able to parse it and create a Tree from the data. I'm having difficulty doing this with JSoup, as it appears you can't really traverse the DOM as expected.

For example, code like the following:

```
Elements elList = doc.select("ul");
for (Element el: elList){
  Elements subList = el.select("ul");
  for (Element subEl : subList){
    //do whatever you need to do
  }
}
```

Produces the following results, where it appears it's not "walking" or "traversing" down, but rather keeps selecting the same thing from the doc:

[image]

What is some code that will traverse this list and put it in a tree structure?

Comment: What is the problem traversing the DOM?

Comment: I think the problem is me, that I don't know how to use JSoup properly to traverse the DOM. Basically the problem is that the results for calls like `Element list = doc.select("ul").first();`, if I then call the same code again on the results `Element subList = list.select("ul").first();`, I get the same results as the first call. I guess I'm expecting the library to "consume" only the selected section. Not sure if this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSoup, both the `select()` and the `getElementByTag()` return the current element as part of the results, if it matches the tag.

So when you do `doc.select("ul")`, and do a `select()` on the result, you'll get the same result, as you have already noticed.

The key to doing this properly is to take that first element, and then search *its children*.

Something along the lines of:

```
public static Node processTree( Element elem ) {

     Node result;

     Elements elList = elem.getElementsByTag("ul");

     if ( elList == null || elList.size() == 0 ) {
         return null;
     };

     result = new Node();
     Element current = elList.first();
     elList = current.children();

     // Process LI elements and add them as content to the
     // result Node
     ...

     // Now go down the tree

     if ( elList != null && elList.size() != 0 ) {

        for ( Element el : elList ) {
            Node elTree = processTree( el );
            if ( elTree != null ) {
                result.addChild( elTree );
            }
        }
     }

     return result;
}
```

(This is, of course, just a sketch. `Node` will be your tree structure node. The point of this is to show you that you have to traverse the *children*. You may process the `li` elements in the same loop if you like)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, simple and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

JSoup builds the DOM as a data structure in memory that you can access in a very powerful "random access" way, for example using the excellent css selector implementation. To solve your problem with JSoup you can cycle over the results like this:

```
Elements elList = doc.select("ul");
for (Element el: elList){
    Elements subList = el.select("ul");
    for (Element subEl : subList){
       //do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

However, if you need to traverse very big html files and the files are well structured you may want to use a library like SAX. This avoids holding the whole DOM in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work as expected (which is the source of my problem). I've added a screenshot and example above that you can use to clarify.